# RESTful API for WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0 does not work in POSTMAN

Tags: rest, api, wso2, postman, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying RESTful API for WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0 with POSTMAN. The documentation is [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/apidocs/publisher/index.html#guide). I use POSTMAN instead of directly using curl commands. After importing curl command and setting request body, when I click Send button POSTMAN gives this error. However, curl works fine in the terminal. Can anyone help with this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is due to SSL certificates are being blocked as mentioned in reasons. Go to `File->Settings->General` and turn off `SSL certificate verification` in POSTMAN.